# In a linear mixed model what does the F value represent?

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, spss, f-test

I am examining the output of my linear mixed model in SPSS and need to decide how to report my findings. I was considering just reporting the p-values. However, my supervisor wants me to provide more information. One figure that I have seen reported is the F value from the 'Type III Tests of Fixed Effects' output table.

Could somebody tell me if this is a useful piece of information to include in my paper? What does it represent?     Is it associated with the F value ANOVA tables or is it something completely different?